# Is there a way to change what is serialized by jackson depending on whether collection of entities were fetched eagerly or lazily?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, jackson, spring-data

It's a good practice to use FetchType.LAZY when the collection of entities aren't always needed fetched (it's a very common scenario). My question is if there's a way to "fully" serialize the collection of entities when they are eagerly fetched (serialize all the fields and not only id field) and serialize only their ids when they are lazily fetched?

For example let's supppose that we have two entities which have bidirectional mapped relations: ***Post*** and ***Comment*** as one-to-many and many-to-one relations and they are **lazily fetched**. I don't always need comments for a post, but let's say that they are useful on few occasions. If I would always just serialize only ids from comments of a Post (which I can easily do by using `@JsonIdentityReference` or a custom serializer), I would have to get that list of ids and send a request to get those If I need them.

On the other hand if I would always **fetch comments eagerly** I could serialize them, of course (for example using `@JsonIdentityInfo`to manage bidirectional relationship or writing a custom serializer), but I would always get informations that aren't always needed.

It seems that the best solution is simply to fetch collection of entitites when they are actually needed (for example using `@Query` with `fetch` keyword), but
***How to serialize it in multiple ways depending on entities being fetched or not?***
I've searched for solution, but I just couldn't find a way to tell jackson to 'fully' serialize the collection of entities when they're eagerly fetched (like serialize the content of the comments not only their ids) and serialize only ids when the entities are fetched lazily.

Comment: This sounds like it would cause your JSON-api to become very unstable. Like, what if someone comes after you and rewrites some logic in your app (in a seemingly backwards compatible way). The logic change could then cause some field to no longer be loaded, and therefore also break your JSON-api. I think you should separate the concerns better here, so that your DB-logic can't affect your REST-layer in such a hidden way.

Comment: @marstran Thank you for your answer! What do you mean by "separate the concerns better"? What kind of solution you would implement in your code? I agree with what you have said about the json-api being unstable in this case, but what else can we do? It's really the best option to lazily fetch comments entities and serialize just their ids and if they are needed just send another request to get them (that's the only solution that I can come up with at the moment)?

Comment: I would create two sets of DTO-classes. One with just the IDs, and one with all the data. Then map your JPA entity to the correct class depending on which endpoint is called. By doing it this way, changes to the underlying structure cannot affect your JSON-api. It's just a bit more to code.